# react js download file in chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

im trying to figure out a way to download a file in chunks.
i have an api endpoint that serves a file but wont allow to download more than 10mb per http request.
as i understand the server supports range request header.

i looked at a 3rd party library called StreamSaver.js but couldnt figure out how to define chunk sizes, or if its even then right library to use.

Anyone have an idea about any third party library for react with which i'll be able to pull it off?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the response content type?

Comment: why dont you use a stream instead of chunks?

Comment: @Jhon Ruddell im not too familiar with streams api, but i read it is not currently supported in ie and firefox, and i need a cross browser support.

Comment: @dotconnor the response content type is "application/octet-stream"